# C# semantic highlighting in VS Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I am trying to utilize new feature from VS Code to highlight C# code using new semantics.

While code itself was highlighted successfully, hover tooltip in the same time ignore my changes.
Question is it lack of functionality for this new "Semantic Highlight" feature or i am missing something.

[image]

my settings.json

```json
{
    "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true,
    "csharp.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true,
    "editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
        "enabled": true,
        "rules": {
            "plainKeyword": {
                "foreground": "#ff0000",
            },
            "class": "#ffff00",
            "interface": {
                "foreground": "#00ff00",
                "fontStyle": "italic",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So it successfully detected an `interface`, `class` and `keyword` semantics and set correct style. But in popup it is still default style. (Default Dark theme selected)

I know i can adjust colors for that hover tooltip without semantic, by using:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": [
                    "storage.type.cs",
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#00FF00",
                    "fontStyle": "italic"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

popup will get new style but it does no use C# semantic and unable to understand between class and interface:

[image]

So is this a bug, lack on my knowledge or by design?

Comment: This is indeed an interesting find! I am guessing its because of the Language provider, ie the C# Extension, did you raise an issue @ https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode ?

Comment: No i didn't, not sure if this is OminSharp or VSCode side issue and if this is an issue in first place